# Templated function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to do something like this:
I want the user to provide a return type and an argument (there will always only be one) then I want the user to be able to provide the pointer of a function that matches this criteria. I will be using this to create a timed event.
The issue here is that usually with templates you must provide T and make a new class instance, however in this case I need it kind of a runtime. ex:

```
TimeEvent *explode  = new TimeEvent(int (the return type),data (the argument), explodeFunc (the function pointer);
```

This would then create and set the function pointer. Then the caller simply does explode.call() to call it.
How could I achieve something like this?

Thanks

Comment: guess you aren't using boost?

Comment: Are you saying that the return type (and therefore the function signature) is defined at runtime as opposed to compile time?

Comment: so the type isn't known at compile time?

Comment: @dutt @zdan Yes that is correct because any function taking in 1 argument is fare game

Comment: Well the return type is 'known' in the sense that its the return type of an already created function,

Comment: a consumer of the API, I basically want the ability to create a timed event which will compare the time stamp when the dispatcher gets a tick from a timer and call the function when appropriate.

Comment: If it didn't use Boost, is Vinzenz's solution what your are looking for?  If so, you can write your own limited polymorphic function wrapper and binder.  If not, can you expand on your question?  It's not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: @James McNellis a consumer of the API, I basically want the ability to create a timed event which will compare the time stamp when the dispatcher gets a tick from a timer and call the function when appropriate

Comment: Hm, in that case you need either a lot of time available or boost, as far as I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well [boost.function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/function.html) + [boost.bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html) is something you can use for this:

```
int explodeFunc( std::string const & someString ) {
     std::cout << someString << " exploded" << std::endl;
     return 1;
}
```

and later...

```
boost::function< int() > timeEvent = boost::bind(explodeFunc, "The world"); 
int retVal = timeEvent();
```

But I am not sure if this is what you are looking for

Here a simple version without boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template< typename R >
struct TimeEvent {
    virtual ~TimeEvent(){}
    virtual R call() = 0;
};

template< typename R, typename ParamType >
struct TimeEventT : TimeEvent<R> {
    typedef R (*callback_type)( ParamType const & );
    typedef ParamType param_type;
    TimeEventT( param_type const & param, callback_type cb )
        : TimeEvent<R>()
        , callback_( cb )
        , param_( param )
    {}

    R call() {
        return callback_( param_ );
    }

protected:
    callback_type callback_;
    param_type param_;
};

template< typename R, typename ParamType, typename ParamValueT >
TimeEvent<R> * create_time_event( 
    R (*cb)(ParamType const &),
    ParamValueT const & param
) {
    return new TimeEventT<R, ParamType>( param, cb );
}

int explodeFunc( std::string const & param ) { 
    std::cout << param << " exploded" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

std::string explodeFuncString( std::string const & param ) { 
    return param + " really exploded this time";    
}

int main(){
    std::string param = "The world";
    TimeEvent<int> * timeEvent1 = create_time_event( explodeFunc, param );
    if( timeEvent1 ) {
        timeEvent1->call();
        delete timeEvent1;
    }
    TimeEvent<std::string> * timeEvent2 = create_time_event( explodeFuncString, param );
    if( timeEvent2 ) {
        std::cout << timeEvent2->call() << std::endl;
        delete timeEvent2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope you get the idea and can make it fit your needs.

HTH

Edit: Updated with templated return type.
* Made create_time_event a bit more user friendly

Comment: `timeEvent` will never be null.

Comment: @GMan true because I did not use std::nothrow, I am so used to use that at work, that I always check it -.-

Comment: but isn't there a way to specify the return value too as a template arg?

Comment: @Milo added the example with ReturnType as template parameter